# How to test to the null that the two asymptotes are the same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression, asymptotics, nonlinear

Consider the following dummy data (in `R`)

```
set.seed(12)
X  = rep(c(2,10,50,1e2,5e2,1e3,5e3,1e4,5e4,1e5), each=100)
Y1 = 200 + 1000 * exp(-0.0003 * X) + rnorm(length(X), 0, 50)
Y2 = 130 + 1100 * exp(-0.001 * X) + rnorm(length(X), 0, 50)
```

We want to fit a model of the type `Y ~ A + B exp(-C X)` for both `Y1` and `Y2`

```
m1 = nls(Y1 ~ A + B * exp(C*X), start=c(A=200, B=1000, C=-0.0008))
m2 = nls(Y2 ~ A + B * exp(C*X), start=c(A=200, B=1000, C=-0.0008))
```

I am interested in the value of the asymptote (parameter `A`). Let's call the two asymptote parameters `A1` and `A2` for `Y1` and `Y2`, respectively. From `m1` and `m2`, the best estimate for `A1` is ~203 and for `A2`, it is ~134.

**How can I test to the null that the two asymptotes are the same?**

---

I suppose I could compute a standard error between the two asymptote `A1` and `A2` ($SE_{A1-A2}$) as something like

$$SE_{A1-A2} = \sqrt{\frac{SS_{residuals,p}}{n_1 var(Y_1)}+\frac{SS_{residuals,p}}{n_2 var(Y_2)}}$$

, where

$$SS_{residuals,p} = \frac{SS_{error,1} + SS_{error,2}}{n_1+n_2-2}$$
$$SS_{error,1} = \sum (Y_{1,i} - \hat Y)^2$$
$$SS_{error,2} = \sum (Y_{2,i} - \hat Y)^2$$

and then compute a $t$ value

$$t = \frac{A_1-A_2}{SE_{A1-A2}}$$

and compute to the corresponding P-value with $df = n_1 + n_2 - 2$.

But I have two doubts:

1. I am not sure whether the difference between the estimated asymptotes would follow a normal distribution under the null hypothesis
2. I am not sure if the above equations would be correct anyway.

**Edit after @Whuber comments**

> You could easily confirm [that the sampling distribution of Â A^ would be close to Normal.] intuition by running a simulation based on your example

```
set.seed(1)
nbReps = 1e4

X  = rep(c(2,10,50,1e2,5e2,1e3,5e3,1e4,5e4,1e5), each=100)
As = numeric(nbReps)
for (rep in 1:nbReps)
{
    Y = 200 + 1000 * exp(-0.0003 * X) + rnorm(length(X), 0, 50)
    As[rep] = coefficients(nls(Y ~ A + B * exp(C*X), start=c(A=200, B=1000, C=-0.0008)))[1]
}

h = hist(As, breaks=60)
abline(v=200, lwd=2, col='red')
xfit <- seq(min(As), max(As), length = 40) 
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(As), sd = sd(As)) 
yfit <- yfit * diff(h$mids[1:2]) * length(As) 
lines(xfit, yfit, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Looks pretty normally distributed!

Comment: If you're concerned about non-normality of the distribution of the differences, then consider a bootstrap.  Ordinarily the bootstrap won't work well for small datasets, but you haven't much hope of fitting these models well unless you have large amounts of data anyway.  I suspect non-normality of $\hat A$ would not be an issue unless the errors are themselves strongly skewed, which would contraindicate using `nls` for fitting in the first place: a glm might be a better choice.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! Bootstrapping might indeed be the way to go. I don't think a linear combinations of polynomials could nicely fit this kind of data. Were you thinking about a specific glm?

Comment: Which glm to choose depends both on your functional form and the conditional distributions.  In your code the conditional distributions are Normal, but it's unclear whether that is for convenience in making an illustration or whether it accurately models your situation.

Comment: Sure. I'm happy to assume to models my real data pretty well. It strikes me that the relationship between `X` and `Y` can't be well approximated with a linear sum of polynomial and I have a hard time to imagine a glm work.

Comment: In that case I would expect--this is intuition talking, not the results of any analysis--that the sampling distribution of $\hat A$ would be close to Normal.  The reason is that $A$ is basically positioning the curve determined by $B$ and $C$ up and down in an $(x,y)$ plot, and so will be primarily influenced by the mean of the error terms.  This will be especially the case if many of your data points are near the asymptote.  You could easily confirm this intuition by running a simulation based on your example.